# How to set more than one ansible_python_interpreter variable in ansible

Tags: python, passwords, ansible

I use ansible programming api to manage passwords(update periodically based on pre-determined password) of lots of hosts,but hosts' python interpreter path is different,may be in /"usr/bin" or "/usr/local/bin",how can i tell ansible to try another when one path of them is not right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't define multiple interpreters with `ansible_python_interpreter`, but I guess this should do the trick:

```
ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"
```

`env` is commonly used in scripts as shebang to detect actual interpreter's path.

Comment: ,very appreciated for you answer,i will have a try right now.

Comment: that trick is right,it works.my reputation is too low to give you a upvote.thank you.